# How can I get full OS information without calling powershell?

Tags: windows, operating-system, system-information

ARCH:x86-x64
How can I get the full information about the OS (Architecture, OS name, OS version, installed language, etc) like `systeminfo`, but not using `cmd`, `powershell` but  most of the `cmd` or `powershell` commands are not available on earlier versions of Windows 7, or just this command could be not execute.

Comment: [Use WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go+wmi)

Answer (score 3):

You should try [psutil](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil). It supports Windows as well as Mac and Linux. You can get started with [psutil/host.PlatformInformation](https://godoc.org/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/host#PlatformInformation) to retrieve OS name and version.

Comment: Sry, i forgot architecture of OS x86-x64 (for 64 bit this doesnt work)